# Doxywizard Equivaelent for Windows OS

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have been using doxywizard ubuntu since long and I know it can run on MACos as well but does anyone really know its equivalent in the Windows OS. There is no build repository on Github for Windows.

And if the answer is no please suggest any other good documentation tool for C++ and python.(GUI support is must)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows binaries of Doxygen also include the GUI.

More information [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html).

Comment: When I try to run cmake command both in(git and cmd it gives me error) like Piyushkumar@Megamind MINGW64 ~/doxygen/build (master)
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
bash: cmake: command not found
How can I solve this?

Comment: @PiyushBhuva Like Joaquin write there is an executable available in the Windows distribution and this distribution can be installed and you have the `doxygwizard` and the`doxygen` executable available. There is no direct need for building something yourself unless you want to fix / develop something yourself or use the latest master version. When using cmake you should not use `cmake "Unix Makefiles"` but probably `cmake "MinGW Makefiles"` (see e.g. `cmake --help`).

Comment: @albert That makes a total sense. Thanks a ton.